# Two CSS-only shapes design for email signature

Tags: html, css, email, svg, signature

First, before spending more hours trying to figure this out I'd like your feedback on css only shapes for email signatures? Do they display well and are they compatible with most email clients ?

I've designed an email signature with svg logo and social media icons just to realize Outlook and other client don't display those.
https://4thsi.com/signature/svg/florian.html

The reason I want to avoid png is so the signature displays directly without users having to accept/download attachments.

Our logo is very simple, so I thought maybe a CSS only code would display correctly?

I've tried with this tool with no success: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Should I continue trying or it's pointless because it won't display correctly? If it does, any recommendation on how to combine two shapes with 2 different colors?

Comment: Generally avoid trying anything too "fancy" in emails. In personal experience, even if I literally embed the image as an attached file (following all the specs to the letter) then email clients still "block remote content".

Comment: for an email and such a simple logo, this kind of html/inline-style should be fine : `<div title="Our Logo" style="font-size:16px;background:#29aee4;width:10em;padding-top:10em;position:relative;"><div style="position:absolute;right:0;top:0;border-bottom:solid white 0.5em;border-left:0.5em solid white;width:4.5em;padding-top:4.5em;background:#f26922"></div></div>` to replace your SVG . resize it via font-size here it is 16px, could be any other value.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Genius! I didn't even consider straight html!

Comment: well outlook didn't really like it, https://nimb.ws/qzj9PB

Comment: okay, use height instead padding and float instead position :`<div title="Our Logo" style="font-size:16px;background:#29aee4;width:10em;height:10em;"><div style="float:right;border-bottom:solid white 0.5em;border-left:0.5em solid white;width:4.5em;height:4.5em;background:#f26922"></div></div>` else make a table of 4 cells like in the old days ;)

Comment: https://nimb.ws/hRw7Q8
looks like that when copying in outlook web  : (

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parent and two child `div`s (all squares, with different width/height settings), using `position: relative` for the parent and `position: absolute` for both children, and with settings similar to the example below. The child divs are both anchored to the top right corner of the parent by using `top: 0` and `right: 0`

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}

.c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

As a variation, you can also use only two `div`s, with the child div having a white border left and bottom:

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @johannes! but outlook displays it like that : https://nimb.ws/ULRfbT

Comment: Which of my versions is that? If it's the second one, you could try to use `left: 50%` (or half of the width in pixels) instead of `right: 0` for the smaller square (`.b`)

Comment: It was the second one. works well on an html page by outlook looks like that when pasting. https://nimb.ws/Zw1C3H